# Remove email recipients on ItemSend

Tags: vba, outlook

Goal: Silently (no dialog box) delete one or more email addresses from recipient collection on ItemSend.

Seems I need to remove recipients by name or index. How do I obtain the index of the email or match it to an SMTP address.

I found some code at the bottom of this message that obtains the SMTP address, but can't find code that I need to start with which is to simply remove a recipient. Then looping it all and matching to an SMTP address seems daunting.

What I'd like to happen

```
Sub DoNotEmailTheseAddresses()
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Set Msg = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With Msg
        run through IndexNumber to find recipients in To:, CC:, and BCC: collection
        
        If RecipientIndexNumber.SMTPaddress = "somebody@adomain.com"
            RecipientIndexNumber.SMTPaddress.Remove
        
        If RecipientIndexNumber.SMTPaddress = "somebodyELSEtoo@adomain.com"
            RecipientIndexNumber.SMTPaddress.Remove
        
    End With
End Sub
```

....and off goes the email with somebody@adomain.com and somebodyELSEtoo@adomain.com handily removed.

Getting the corresponding SMTP address code is on MSDN site. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866259(v=office.15).aspx

```
Sub GetSMTPAddressForRecipients(mail As Outlook.MailItem) 
    Dim recips As Outlook.Recipients 
    Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient 
    Dim pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor 
    Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = _ 
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E" 
    Set recips = mail.Recipients 
    For Each recip In recips 
        Set pa = recip.PropertyAccessor 
        Debug.Print recip.name & " SMTP=" _ 
           & pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) 
    Next 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not that far away....

For each mail-address you want to remove, you have to go through all recipients and check if they have this mail-address. If yes, remove them. therefor I have put this into a separate function, which you can call for each mail-address you want to remove.

```
Public Sub newItem_Open(Cancel As Boolean)
  Call removerecipi(newItem, "somebody@adomain.com")
End Sub

Function removerecipi(mailitem As Outlook.mailitem, rec_mail As String)
    Dim i As Long
restart:
    For i = 1 To mailitem.Recipients.Count
        If i > mailitem.Recipients.Count Then GoTo restart
        If mailitem.Recipients(i).SmtpAddress = rec_mail Then mailitem.Recipients.Remove i
    Next i
End Function
```

why is the restart necessary: after removing one recipient, the mailItem.Recipients.Count needs to be reset. There are also other Solutions, however this one works fine.

Comment: Thank you for writing here.  I was not able to get the suggested code to work, but I did get the answer elsewhere.  Your code may in fact work fine but with my limited VBA knowledge, I couldn't implement it.

For anyone interested, the code that I did get to work is found here on MSDN:  [click here to see solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/283f345a-7409-4bfc-9507-2f840fd160e1/remove-recipient-from-recipient-collection?forum=outlookdev&prof=required)